# IE9 not working, but Safari is?

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer-9

Last week I updated my iTunes, and the Safari browser was installed on my computer. After I restarted my computer with the updates, my internet explorer was not working. The Safari browser is working fine. I had IE8, so I updated to IE9, thinking that may have been the problem. It still is not working. I have tried opening explorer and going to msn.com, microsoft, etc, and the same thing always comes up "internet explorer cannot display webpage". When I click to diagnose, it says no problem can be found. I use Norton, and the scans come up fine. I use Windows Vista. I want my explorer back- can anyone please help me?

Comment: an apple a day keeps windows away

Comment: why would you even want to use IE?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you haven't done anything different from installing iTunes/Safari? Try that:

1. Scan your computer with an anti-malware. If found and cleaned, try to connect. Else go to 2.
2. Clear IE cache (temporary internet files, cookies etc.) and disable all add-ons. Try to connect. If it does not function, go to 3.
3. Install Chrome or Firefox and uninstall iTunes/Safari. Try to connect. If it does not function, go to 4.
4. Have you tried to recover Windows to the last restore point before the installation of iTunes?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a plugin, Norton, or malware is affecting IE.

In Internet Explorer 9 - Click on the gear on the top-right corner of the browser window. Select "Internet Options" from the menu that pops up, with the Internet Options dialogue up - navigate to the "Advanced" tab... on the bottom of the window you will want to click "Restore Advanced Settings" and "Reset..." - when clicking the Reset button, a box will pop up and all you need to do is click "OK". Restart Internet Explorer and see if your browsing is back.

If this doesn't work, you will want to run tdsskiller from Kaspersky or remove and re-install Norton.

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed malware you should not forget to check you LAN Settings.

1. Click the gear in the upper right hand corner
2. Click on Internet Options
3. Go to the Connections Tab
4. Click on the LAN Settings tab

Make sure this is set to automatically detect and does not have script or proxy server setup. I have encountered malware that will change this setting to http://127.0.0.1 . Which obviously means you will get no where.

You should also scan your pc in safe mode with networking so that you can do updates for your antimalware and antispyware tools. This will also stop most malware from loading, potentially you may have to disable system protection **only if** the malware continues to propogate after cleaning. Use several tools as well so you get the best detection.